# Install driver on windows? same for ubuntu?

Tags: drivers

I just have a quick question,

I'm planning on dual booting my computer with Windows/Ubuntu 12.04. If I install a driver for a graphic card on Windows? would I have to do the same for Ubuntu or does it transfer over?

Best,

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to download a graphics driver separately for Ubuntu.
By default the open source graphics driver comes installed in the kernel.

If you are having problems with the default driver or need a proprietary one, get it from the System Settings > Additional Drivers window (for 12.04 and older) or Software Sources > Additional Drivers (12.10 and newer).

These links might help you

For ATI : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

And Nvidia : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows installation and Ubuntu installation are completely separate.  Any software changes, installations, or settings done in Windows will have no impact on Ubuntu.

Furthermore, the driver you install on Windows will be made specifically *for* Windows.  You will have to find the Ubuntu equivalent and install that on your Ubuntu installation separately.